# Android Outlook calendar not listed in intent chooser

Tags: android, calendar, outlook

I have the the Outlook app installed on a GS6 and the following code to insert a calendar event:

```
            Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, cal.getTimeInMillis());
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, cal.getTimeInMillis());
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(calendarIntent, "Add to Calendar"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.w(_TAG, "could not create intent chooser: " + ex.toString());
            }
```

However a chooser doesn't come up, the S Planner app launches instead.  What can I do to prevent the S Planner app from launching and instead display a chooser with S Planner and Outlook?  Is this possibly a problem with Outlook not being recognized as a calendar receiver?

Comment: Outlook apparently does not have an `<activity>` with an `<intent-filter>` that matches your `Intent`. See if Microsoft has any documentation for `Intent` structures that work with Outlook's calendar activities.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I searched for documentation that would indicate Outlook's calendar intent structures but couldn't find any.  I did however download the Google Calendar app and verified I'm now getting the intent chooser with S Planner and Google Calendar options, just no Outlook option.  I assume posting calendar events to the Outlook calendar isn't currently an option.